# Drupal Taxonomy Architecture Design for World Geography

Tags: drupal, google-maps, architecture, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I am building a Drupal 7 site to use the Google Maps API coupled with the GeoField module. I need to architect the site so that a node (perhaps a custom content type with the geofield used) represents a location on the map.

Would a geo field in the node's content type be sufficient or should I also create a hierarchy taxonomy representing the hierarchy of the world?

```
Continents > Countries > Regions > Cities > Districts
North America > United States of America > California > San Francisco > Golden Gate
```

Each blip on the map represents a location which might be a business listing or an event. I am thinking it would be duplicating things to create the taxonomy.

Comment: I am not sure about the geo field module. You can do put the map in node-customcontenttype.tpl.php  .

Comment: Finally got an answer on the Drupal Q&A site.

[http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22027/recommended-taxonomy-structure-for-destinations-site][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22027/recommended-taxonomy-structure-for-destinations-site